# How to show name of played sound (on keypress) in a field [javascript or jquery]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm trying to figure this out but it isn't working yet. So I want to trigger a sound on keypress and then show the name of the sound in a field. It has to show the id of QQ as it's name. I've got two codes, one isn't working at all and one lets me hear the sound on keypress but doesn't show the name of the sound (I can't figure out how to implement it). My codes so far are this:

Not working solution with jQuery:

```js
$(".drum-pad").on('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 81){
        $(e.target).children('audio.clip')[0].play();
        $("#track").text(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Half-working solution with pure JavaScript:

```ts
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
        document.getElementById('Q').play();
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="drum-machine">
    <div id="display">
        <p id="track"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="QQ" class="drum-pad">
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" class="clip" id="Q"></audio>
        Q
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share html of element Q

Comment: ^ Full HTML would be better

Comment: I edited HTML in but it doesn't look good, I don't know why. I'm sorry it's my second time posting so I don't know where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keydown` on `document` works in jQuery, so the below code should work. [Javascript Key Codes](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 81){
        $('#Q').get(0).play();

        var text = $("#Q").closest('div').attr('id');
        $("#track").text(text);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="drum-machine">
    <div id="display">
        <p id="track"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="QQ" class="drum-pad">
        <audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" class="clip" id="Q"></audio>
        Q
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:Get parent of audio played and put text of it in track div.

Note: Please include jquery library in your code

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
        document.getElementById('Q').play();
        var parent = $("#Q").parent();
        $("#track").text(parent.attr("id"));
    }
});
```

To handle it generically for all `drum-pad` use below code

```
$(document).on('keydown','.drum-pad', function (e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 81){
        $(this).find("audio").get(0).play();
        $("#track").text($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly on the right track and I'll see what I can do with that :) It has to show the id of QQ though, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: In that case use `parent.attr("id")`, I have edited in my post

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is bad idea to write "if" for each key. Try something like this:

```
<div id="drum-machine">
   <div id="display">
     <p id="track"></p>
   </div>
   <div id="QQ" class="drum-pad">
      <audio id="key-81" data-name="Heater 1" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" class="clip" ></audio>
   Q</div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var el = document.getElementById('key'+e.keyCode)
    el.play()
    document.getElementById('track').innerText = el.innerText
});
```